# Upload large image to my application in java netbeans

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans

I am creating an application. I want to upload a image and save to my database..when run my application it run successfully for small size images but I can't save large size images to my database..when I going save large size image like 2 MB it prompt an error like

com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (2491559 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.

why comes like this error..how can i solved it
This My Code

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
if (evt.getSource() == jButton1)
     {
        int x = 0;
        String s1 = jTextField1.getText().trim();
        String s2 = jTextField2.getText();

        char[] s3 = jPasswordField1.getPassword();
        char[] s4 = jPasswordField2.getPassword(); 
        String s8 = new String(s3);
        String s9 = new String(s4);

        String s5 = jTextField5.getText();
        String s6 = jTextField6.getText();
        String s7 = jTextField7.getText();

        if(s8.equals(s9))
        {
            try
            {
                File image1 = new File(filename);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image1);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {

            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
        }
        cat_image = bos.toByteArray();
        System.out.println(cat_image.length);

            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into reg values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                ps.setString(1, s1);
                ps.setString(2, s2);
                ps.setString(3, s8);
                ps.setString(4, s5);
                ps.setString(5, s6);
                ps.setString(6, s7);
                ps.setBytes(7, cat_image);
                int rs = ps.executeUpdate();
                x++;
                if (x > 0) 
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jButton1, "Data Saved Successfully");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jButton1, "Password Dosn't match");
        }

}
 else
{
    jTextField1.setText("");
        jTextField2.setText("");
        jPasswordField1.setText("");
        jPasswordField2.setText("");
        jTextField5.setText("");
        jTextField6.setText("");
        jTextField7.setText("");
}



// TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
jTextField1.setText("");
        jTextField2.setText("");
        jPasswordField1.setText("");
        jPasswordField2.setText("");
        jTextField5.setText("");
        jTextField6.setText("");
        jTextField7.setText("");



// TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
    jTextField3.setText(filename);


       // int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    //if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(filename);
            jLabel8.setIcon(icon);

    //}




 // TODO add your handling code here:
 }
```

Comment: `com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (2491559 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.` It seems to be a problem on server side so you probably should look the solution there and not in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception states the problem is related to the server's [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) variable that defines the maximum size of one packet. See [Packet Too Large](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html) topic that describes how to modify server's configurations files to increase the value of this variable. Also see [Using Option Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) for more details on configuration files.